# Fetch sum of source_count in nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

In nifi I'm getting flow files with JSON content as below, there are multiple flow files where we get different values so need to add all the values in order to fetch the total source_count. Any methods we can do that in nifi.

```json
{ "source_count":"200" }
```

like this we will get some n number of flow files each with different values .

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `Counters` that are available in the NiFi to hold the values in the flowfiles and keep summing them as you read through each file.

[image: sample flow]

So in the above sample flow I have two `GenerateFlowFile` processors

1 -> {"source_count":"200"}
2 -> {"source_count":"300"}

Then I use the `EvaluateJsonPath` processor to fetch the source_count value and store it into a variable.

After which I use a `UpdateCounter` processor to keep the summing the JSON files read, in the place of the `Delta` you would need to specify the attribute name defined in the previous step.

Finally you can see the value in the Counters tab of the NiFi UI, and yes you can get the value from the counters using the NiFi [Rest API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) by using a `InvokeHTTP` processor

[image: Counters UI Tab]

[image: EvaluateJsonPath Properties]

[image: UpdateCounter Properties]

#### Counters Fetch & Reset

To fetch the data from the counters you would use the `/counters` API to get the values of all the counters that are available.

```
curl --location 'https://<host_name>/nifi-api/counters' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <Your_Token>'
```

Next Step, you can extract the value from the JSON response using the JSON evaluate processors, as its relatively easy as you know the name of the counter that was set by you.

Now, to reset the counter you would call the API `/counters/{id}` the ID you can also get from the previous call. This would reset the value to `0`

You can refer the https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html doc as you can find more information.

```json
{
    "counter": {
        "id": "e9fe8cc0-9212-3dcf-bfa1-eb0ccfd6b0fc",
        "context": "All UpdateCounter's",
        "name": "test_counter",
        "valueCount": 0,
        "value": "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls provide the properties of Evaluate and Update counter as Im new to nifi and can I get the value from counters tab to a flow file @DataWrangler

Comment: Added the images of the properties page @Ram, hope this helps

Comment: Hi, @DataWrangler I'm getting my count logged in counters tab, but is there a way that I could fetch the count from the counters tab into a flowfile.

Comment: @Ram, yes you can get the value from the counters using the NiFi Rest API by using a InvokeHTTP processor

Comment: can you please share sample API's for fetching and reseting the counter

Comment: @Ram, expanded the answer to also provide details on how to fetch the values from counters and reset them